# My question was closed as exact duplicate, but instead was exactly the opposite

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions

my [question](https://superuser.com/questions/237489/music-player-that-can-speed-up-slow-down-the-music) has been closed as exact duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/220914/is-there-software-to-automatically-change-song-speed-without-transposing-it) - but **has anyone bothered to read it**? Or do you just blindly cast close votes? The "duplicate" is asking about exactly the opposite of what I wanted - I wanted to listen to songs with transposing them, while the supposed dupe asked for listening to songs without transposing (changing pitch).

I don't know what's going on around here, but maybe someone could leave a comment or something, but I'm disappointed in the power users as clearly they just flocked down here and produce enough votes to close a random question.

Comment: While I can understand your frustration at question being closed ( yes I am one of the people who voted to close) - you *could* tone down a harshness a bit. Nevertheless, voted to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This site is community-driven. People make mistakes. That's why it needs 5 votes to close a question. Fortunately, these mistakes can be reversed, as I suggested you request in my comment.

I also happened to cast close votes by mistake before. Differences in questions are sometimes subtle (as I suspect is the problem in your case). In addition, many users don't bother to search through other questions, or even look through the list of suggested topics that is presented when they finish their question title. Some regulars will then more readily click that close vote link. It's nothing that cannot be reversed.